# Weird paypal api issue

Tags: c#, paypal

I just started using the Paypal API and I'm stuck on this problem.

I generate a paypal request in code and when I send it I get back the following.

```
TIMESTAMP=2011-05-16T01:26:37Z
CORRELATIONID=6d4327d15421f
ACK=Failure
L_ERRORCODE0=10001
L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal Error
L_LONGMESSAGE0=Timeout processing request
```

When I run through the debugger and copy the generated request url and paste it into my web browser, I get a success response....

I'm sending the request like this - c#

```
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 req.Method = "POST";
 req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

The same request, but one sent by code, and one copied to the browser produces to different results. Why is that?

Comment: could a proxy be involved in one request, and not the other?

Comment: I don't use a proxy in the code, or have one setup in my browser

Comment: If you're copying and pasting a URL into the browser, then that sounds like a GET request, not a POST. You're C# code seems to be trying to do a POST. Maybe try doing a GET with that URL....

Comment: Your right! Now I'm really confused since the API seems to want people to use POST, I'm surprised Get works

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. When remove the

```
request.Method ="POST";
```

line, problem is solved.